# Laragon, laravel symbolyc link does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.6, laragon

I'm using laravel with laragon, everything works fine exept that when I upload images they return `404` , and `public/storage` is empty however `storage/app/public` has the files , also `public/public` has the files , so it creates a wrong folder public inside the public folder, I did run the `php artisan storage:link command` as I said it created the storage link I can see it in my editor, however the files go to the `public/public` instead of `public/storage` , how can I get it work? I guess it's laragon's issue coz it works in other environments , also I run my website with a "named" url : myproject.test , and I use apache2 as a web server, please help to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on linux, you can use

```
ln -s [source] [virtual]
```

to create virtual links. On windows, you can use

```
mklink /j [virtual] [source]
```

to do the same.

Note that you may need to use full paths to create the link. I use this method on laragon and it works. Check if it works by double clicking the link after you create the symlinks if they go to the desired folder. If it doesn't, something is wrong with the configuration.

---

**Bonus**

I created a console command to automatize things, maybe you can use that:

Usage: `php artisan install:symlink`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class installSymlink extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'install:symlink';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'This artisan command installs pinpacker symlinks';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //

        $links = ["./public/thumbnails","./public/resized"];
        $folders = ["./storage/app/public/thumbnails/","./storage/app/public/resized/"];

        chdir(base_path());

        try {
            if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
                foreach($links as $i => $link){
                    $command = 'mklink /j "' . str_replace('/', '\\', $link) . '" "' . str_replace('/', '\\', $folders[$i]) . '"';
                    echo $command."\n";
                    exec($command);
                }
            } else {
                foreach($links as $i => $link){
                    $command = 'ln -s ' . realpath($folders[$i]) . ' ' . $link;
                    echo $command ."\n";
                    exec($command);
                }
            }
            printf("Symlinks created.\n");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            printf($e->getMessage());
            print_r($e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi , thanks but it does not work , I'm on windows 10, and my laragon is on C:/laragon I run the mklink /j [virtual] [source] command , and it created the folder but the files are not synced so the virtual folder is not being updated when the changes take place :( , in my xammp all works fine